# Como montar uma expressão lambda e passá-la por parâmetro para uma função Genérica?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, expressões-lambda, genéricos

Preciso passar dois parâmetros para uma função genérica que retorne dados do banco e selecionar apenas algumas colunas específicas para exibir em um `DataGridView`.

```
public List<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Predicate, 
                            Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> Select)
{
       var query = Context.Set<TEntity>()
          .Where(Predicate)
          .Select(Select).ToList();
       return query;
}
```

Para a consulta que irei realizar, não preciso passar um `Predicate`, preciso apenas passar um `Select` que me retorne:

```
PessoaId, 
Login, 
Senha,  
UsuarioTipoId, 
Descricao(UsuarioTipo), 
PessoaTipoId, 
Descricao(PessoaTipo).
```

Se o Usuário for pessoa física, exibir os campos:

```
NomeCompleto, 
Apelido,
DataNascimento
```

mas se ele for uma pessoa jurídica, exibir os campos:

```
RazaoSocial, 
NomeFantasia,
DataAbertura
```

É uma expressão um pouco complexa. É possível de ser feita e como Passá-la por parâmetro?

Abaixo, seguem as classes:

```
//CLASSES MODEL
public class PessoaModel
    {
        public int PessoaId { get; set; }
        public int PessoaTipoId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataInclusao { get; set; }

        public virtual PessoaTipoModel PessoaTipo { get; set; }
        public virtual PessoaFisicaModel PessoaFisica { get; set; }
        public virtual PessoaJuridicaModel PessoaJuridica { get; set; }
    }

 public class UsuarioModel : PessoaModel
 {
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
        public int UsuarioTipoId { get; set; }

        public virtual UsuarioTipoModel UsuarioTipo { get; set; }

  }

 public class PessoaFisicaModel
 {
        public int PessoaId { get; set; }
        public string NomeCompleto { get; set; }
        public string Apelido { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
        public string CPF { get; set; }

        public virtual PessoaModel Pessoa { get; set; }
 }

 public class PessoaJuridicaModel
 {
        public int PessoaId { get; set; }
        public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
        public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataAbertura { get; set; }
        public string CNPJ { get; set; }

        public virtual PessoaModel Pessoa { get; set; }
 }


 //CARREGAMENTO DO DATAGRIDVIEW
 UsuarioRepository UsuarioRepositorio = new UsuarioRepository();
 dgUsuarios.DataSource = UsuarioRepositorio.GetAll();
```

Precisava de algo mais ou menos assim (Passagem de parametros):

```
dgPesquisar.DataSource = UsuarioRepositorio.GetAll(null, u => u.login,  u.Senha, u.NOmeCompleto );
```

Comment: você precisa fazer naquele `GetAll` só a expressão de Select e para definir qual é o tipo de Pessoa é pelo campo `PessoaTipoId ` qual é o valor?

Comment: faltou colocar o código de classes: `UsuarioTipoModel` e `PessoaTipoModel`

Comment: PessoaId ===> 1 P. física e 2 P. Jurídica....

Comment: É PessoaTipoId ou PessoaId? e falta as duas classes `UsuarioTipoModel` e `PessoaTipoModel`

Comment: Se seu objetivo for retorna os dois tipos de pessoas no seu GetAll(), com listas (campos no select) diferentes, isso não tem como ser feito,  ou seja você não pode retornar uma lista new PessoaFisicaModel e outra new PessoaJuridicaModel ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 2):

Você quer fazer da maneira simples e flexível ou complicada e engessada?

```
using (var context = new MyWonderfulRepositoryContext())
{
    dgUsuarios.DataSource = 
        from pessoa in context.Pessoas
        where /* minha condicao */
        select new PessoaFisicaModel {
            /* monte o seu objecto aqui */
        }
}
```

Mas eu quero implementar o `Repository Pattern` porque alguém disse que é uma boa ideia... o `DbSet<T>` já o faz e bem melhor que você...

E quanto ao `Unit of Work`? o `DbContext` também já implementa este cara.

Ah, mas não gosto do `Entity Framework` e vou <s>sabotar o projeto</s> para que troquem o `ORM` pelo `NHibernate` daqui a 6 meses.

neste caso crie uma `class library` com classes estáticas que extendam o `DbContext`:

```
public static PessoasContextExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<PessoaFisicaModel> GetPessoasFisicas(this MyWonderfulRepositoryContext context)
    {
        return from pessoa in context.Pessoas
            where /* minha condicao */
            select new PessoaFisicaModel {
                /* monte o seu objecto aqui */
            };
    }
}
```

e na sua aplicação faz assim.:

```
dgUsuarios.DataSource = context.GetPessoasFisicas();
```

e daqui a 6 meses você muda a assinatura das suas extensões para `GetPessoasFisicas(this MyWonderfulSession session)`.

Answer (score 0):

Olha, Pelo que entendi, o GetAll vai voltar todos as pessoas, fisicas ou juridicas correto, e o que muda são os campos dependendo do tipo?

Nesse caso as dias saidas que parece corretas é na classe Pessoa ter esse método abastrato, e implementar ele nas classes que o herdarem. Mais ou menos assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestePessoa
{
    public abstract class Pessoa
    {
        public int PessoaId { get; set; }
        public int PessoaTipoId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataInclusao { get; set; }

        public abstract List<Pessoa> GetAll(Pessoa filtro);
    }
}
```

E as classes que implementam ela

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestePessoa
{
    public class PessoaFisica : Pessoa
    {
        public string NomeCompleto { get; set; }
        public string Apelido { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
        public string CPF { get; set; }

        public override List<Pessoa> GetAll(Pessoa filtro)
        {
            var filtroPEssoaFisica = filtro as PessoaFisica;
            var retorno = new List<Pessoa>();

            //faça sua busca aqui e popule retorno com PessoaFisica fazendo cast para Pessoa


            return retorno;
        }
    }
}
```

E também:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestePessoa
{
    public class PessoaJuridica : Pessoa
    {
        public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
        public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DataAbertura { get; set; }
        public string CNPJ { get; set; }


        public override List<Pessoa> GetAll(Pessoa filtro)
        {
            var filtroPessoaJur = filtro as PessoaJuridica;
            var retorno = new List<Pessoa>();

            //faça sua busca aqui e popule retorno com PessoaJuridica fazendo cast para Pessoa


            return retorno;
        }
    }
}
```

Outra forma, seria usar um delegate da vida, 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/900fyy8e.aspx

Comment: Valeu joe, mas aí eu teria que mudar as classes... No caso, apenas a classe Usuario herdaria de Pessoa. Já PessoFisica e PessoaJuridica são relacionamentos de composição. Quando instancio a classe Usuario, já consigo ter acesso a todas as informações das outras classes.... Precisava de algo mais ou menos assim (Passagem de parametros): dgPesquisar.DataSource = UsuarioRepositorio.GetAll(null, u => u.login, u.Senha, u.NOmeCompleto );

Comment: Entendi. De qualquer maneira, vc pode alterar a GetAll então para receber um delegate. Depois se quiser eu faço o exemplo e passo.

Comment: Poxa joe, se vc fizesse um exemplo, eu te agradeceria muito... Se quiser, posso te mandar uma cópia do projeto...

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Preparei um exemplo de método genérico para você usar como você pediu(ou perguntou se era possível rs, c# é possível =D )

Método genérico:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Listar<TEntity>(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condicao, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> campos) where TEntity : class
    {
        /*Verifica se possui condição*/
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = condicao != null ? 
                        _bd.Set<TEntity>().Where(condicao) : 
                        _bd.Set<TEntity>();

        /*Verifica se possui campos fitrados*/
        var result = campos != null ? 
                    query.Select(campos).ToList() : 
                    query.ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

Chamada para o método genérico:

```
public IEnumerable<PessoaFisicaModel> RecuperarPessoasFisicas()
    {
        /*Aqui ele vai buscar todas as pessoas físicas sem a condição where informada*/
        var todasPessoasFisicas = 
            Listar<PessoaFisicaModel>(null, s => new PessoaFisicaModel { PessoaId = s.PessoaId, NomeCompleto = s.NomeCompleto });

        /*Aqui ele vai buscar todas as pessoas que começam com a letra L*/
        var pessoasComLetraL = 
            Listar<PessoaFisicaModel>(
                    w => w.NomeCompleto.StartWith("L"), 
                    s => new PessoaFisicaModel { PessoaId = s.PessoaId, NomeCompleto = s.NomeCompleto });
    }
```

Comment: Esse método genérico não funciona, porque os métodos Where e Select não causam efeitos colaterais (não mudam o estado do objeto), ou seja, precisa alterar para `query = query.Where(@where)`. Também tem um problema com o uso de palavras reservas, tem que trocar as variáveis `where` e `select`, respectivamente para `@where` e `@select`.

Comment: Valeu Gabriel, atualizei o método e testei.